# Sitecore replicate changes throw all the pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm trying to implement a menu in sitecore page. Menu that will be available in all the pages.

I can do a rendering that goes to some specific datasource and assign the rendering to a placeholder inside Design Layout of the layout.

However how can they edit the datasource (order, ammount of elements, etc..) item in page A that will be also replicated in page B.

Without going through all the pages to change order, color, text, items etc...

Comment: Other problem is that i was trying to add "Action List" field type to a template but when i try to edit it in the content editor it crash saying XML empty or null after creating an item with that specific template

Answer (score 1):

To do that you will want to create a new data template that holds the shareable content on it. So it would have fields for navigation items etc... any setting that you wanted to be shared across pages.

Then in your rendering, you can set the Datasource to this item. Any changes to that item would be reflected across all pages that use it.

You should add the rendering to the standard values of your page templates and set the Datasource to your main default navigation item, then all new pages will get the navigation ready setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've doubt about shareable content. I can't find that info in the Sitecore 8.1 Item.

Comment: "Shareable content" just refers to the content you want to share across your pages as you stated in your question. So a multilist to pick the items for navigation and set the order etc...

Comment: The editor would be able to edit the content in the Experience Editor? or this content only can be changed in content editor?

Also the menu will have submenus and those submenus with different layout, how to manage this changes of layout of the submenu in the sitecore doing the shareable content?

Answer (score 0):

You need design your view in such a way that it should be editable in experience editor mode.

If you have implemented using Glass Mapper there is good section on how to use [Edit Frame](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/GlassHtml).

Also you can check below community blog. for more details.

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/render-field-values-for-mvc-solutions-using-the-sitecore-asp-net-web-cms